# Need to Update based on ID and Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL statement, which I think should update 1 field, using some pretty simple standard deviation logic, and based on ID and Date.  I think the ID and Date has to be included to get everything aligned right.  So, here is the code that I'm testing.

```
UPDATE Price_Test2
    SET Vol30Days = STDEV(PX_BID) OVER (ORDER BY ID_CUSIP, AsOfDate ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) FROM Price_Test2
WHERE ID_CUSIP in (SELECT DISTINCT ID_CUSIP FROM Price_Test2)
```

It seems like it should work fine, but something is off because I'm getting an error that says: Cannot use both a From clause and a subquery in the where clause or in the data values list in an Update statement.

I am using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: use `CTE` or `DERIVED QUERY` to calculate those `Vol??Days` and then update in  outer query. Also remove the `WHERE` clause. It is not doing anything. As for `ORDER BY` you can't have `UPDATE` with `ORDER BY` together

Comment: you can't update table with `window functions` directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using aggregation functions in an `update`.  What you want is an updatable subquery (or CTE):

```
UPDATE p
    SET Vol30Days = new_Vol30Days,
        Vol60Days = new_Vol60Days,
        Vol90Days = new_Vol90Days
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             STDEV(PX_BID) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as new_Vol30day,
             STDEV(PX_BID) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 60 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as new_Vol60day,
             STDEV(PX_BID) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 90 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as new_Vol60day
      FROM prices p
     ) p;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  The concept basically makes sense, but wouldn't I need to include the IDs in the ORDER BY?  Also, I'm getting this error: FROM clause in UPDATE and DELETE statements cannot contain subquery sources or joins.

Comment: @Ash . . . I don't know if `id` is needed.  You have not provided sample data and desired results.  The `FROM` clause can certainly contain subqueries and joins in SQL Server.

Comment: Oh, wait, I think my syntax was wrong.  So, I am working in Azure Data Warehouse. Apparently, it doesn't support CTEs.  I'm getting this error message now: 
Common table expressions followed by INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE are not supported in this version.
How can I do this in 3 separate steps?

Comment: @ASH . . . In that case, you might need subqueries.

Comment: I just updated my original post with my SQL and my error.  Thoughts?